# Do any browsers support HTML5's context menu?

Tags: html, contextmenu

Do any browsers support the [HTML5 context menu attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#attr-contextmenu)?

Answer (score 15):

This has been added to Firefox 8.

See this for an example of it working https://bug617528.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=554309

Comment: Chrome also implemented it for a while but then rolled back all that and said they won't implement it. W3 will remove it from the HTML5.1 specs if it's not implemented in at least 2 browsers...it is currently "at risk".

Answer (score 7):

Right now, the contextmenu attribute is not supported by any browser version. According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=contextmenu) it doesn't have support for any current browser versions (IE 9, Firefox 4, Safari 5, Chrome 11, Opera 11.1, or any mobile browsers - iOS, Opera, or Android). It is unknown if it will be supported in future versions.

It was discussed in [April 2010](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2010-April/012608.html) regarding adding it to Webkit. But it doesn't look like it's been added to the nightlies yet.

Comment: 4 years later it's still not supported :-(

Comment: Chrome added it in test builds, but just decided to remove it due to concerns about issues with the spec's API.  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87553&desc=2#c58

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)) wiki page for now there is no any popular layout engine except Firefox's Gecko that fully supports the *menu* element. Meanwhile, you can try some script solutions, like [jQuery Context Menu Plugin](https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu).

Comment: Hi, the second link is broken. Is it something like http://plugins.jquery.com/contextMenu/?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for HTML5 feature detection.

Answer (score 1):

It is working well here with Firefox 9.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 8 Aurora implements this feature. But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me now...

Comment: how is this a usefull answer?

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure it's supported with a polyfill: https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu