# Which browsers currently support the HTML5 contextmenu attribute?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do any browsers support HTML5's context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120588/do-any-browsers-support-html5s-context-menu)

I was wondering which browser currently support the new HTML5 contextmenu attribute?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, March 22 2011, no browsers support it. Not even Firefox 4 which will be released in a few days.